# Why does the reference to local variable return successfully?

Tags: rust, llvm-ir

`call1` and `call2` fails to compile as expected. But call3 compiles rather than throws an error like "cannot return reference to temporary value". Why?

```
struct Demo(i32);

impl Demo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self(22)
    }
}

// Compile error: cannot return reference to temporary value
fn call1<'a>() -> &'a Demo {
    let a = Demo(3);
    &a
}

// Compile error: cannot return reference to temporary value
fn call2<'a>() -> &'a Demo{
    &Demo::new()
}

// Compiles!
fn call3<'a>() -> &'a Demo {
    &Demo(34)
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Jmb. But to sum up the information from the duplicate; the reason ist hat `Demo(34)` is, like string literals, a literal that will get compiled into the executable, and therefore has, by definition, the lifetime `'static`. (That's at least my understanding). It were different if you returned a `&'a mut Demo`, because the "compiling the value into the executable" only works if the value is read-only.